# c++ delete last element of dynamic array

Tags: c++, dynamic, dynamic-memory-allocation, delete-operator

In c++ I took a dynamic array of n elements

```
int* a = new int[n];
```

After shifting left all element of that array, the last element, i.e a[n-1] is useless, and I want to delete it.
And after shifting right I need to delete the first element of array, and to have a pointer to second element, i.e I need to make an array with length of n-1.
How can I do that?

Comment: C++ has no new/delete equivalent of C's `realloc`. So the short answer is, you don't. You make a new array, copy, delete [] the old, etc. Or you do it the way you should in the first place: use a `std::vector<int>`. Of course, you're keeping track of `n` *somewhere*. There's nothing stopping you from just decrementing the `n` cap and ignoring that you have one extra, now-unused slot.

Comment: If you compare your approach with `std::vector`: `std::vector` keeps two values: size and capacity where size is the number of elements in use while capacity is the number of elements allocated. So, deleting the last element with e.g. `std::vector::pop_back()` may result in decrementing size only (a quite cheap operation). Of course, size must always be <= capacity. For enlarging reallocation, `std::vector` might reallocate storage for more than required elements that can reduce the number of necessary reallocations. (Allocation is considered as expensive operation.)

Comment: the "dynamic" in "dynamic array" only refers to the fact that you choose the size at runtime, however once created the size is fixed. If you want a "dynamic array" as in "size can change dynamically" you need to use a `std::vector` (or build one yourself, not recommended)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allocate a new array and copy elements of the original array to the new array.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>

size_t shift_left( int * &a, size_t n )
{
    if ( n )
    {
        int *p = new int [n-1];

        std::copy( a + 1, a + n, p );

        std::swap( a, p );

        delete []p;
    }

    return n == 0 ? n : n - 1;
}

size_t shift_right( int * &a, size_t n )
{
    if ( n )
    {
        int *p = new int [n-1];

        std::copy( a, a + n - 1, p );

        std::swap( a, p );

        delete []p;
    }

    return n == 0 ? n : n - 1;
}

int main() 
{
    size_t n = 10;      
    int *a = new int[n] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    for ( const int *p = a; p != a + n; p++ )
    {
        std::cout << *p << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    n = shift_left( a, n );

    for ( const int *p = a; p != a + n; p++ )
    {
        std::cout << *p << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    n = shift_right( a, n );

    for ( const int *p = a; p != a + n; p++ )
    {
        std::cout << *p << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    delete []a;

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

You can change the functions the following way. When the passed value of n is equal to 1 when just free the original pointer and set it to nullptr.

For example

```
size_t shift_left( int * &a, size_t n )
{
    if ( n )
    {
        if ( n == 1 )
        {
            delete []a;
            a = nullptr;
        }
        else
        {
            int *p = new int [n-1];

            std::copy( a + 1, a + n, p );

            std::swap( a, p );

            delete []p;
        }               
    }

    return n == 0 ? n : n - 1;
}
```

As an alternative you can use the standard container `std::vector` and its member function `erase`.

Or you can consider using `std::valarray`.